# How to parse actual code like stackoverflow/intellisense/etc?

Tags: parsing, xsd, code-structure

I was wondering how stackoverflow parses all sorts of different code and identifies keywords, special characters, whitespace formatting, etc. It does this for most code I believe, and I've noticed it's even sophisticated enough to understand the relationships between everything it parses, like so:

```
String mystring1 = "inquotes"; //incomment
String mystring2 = "inquotes//incomment";
String mystring3 = //incomment"inquotes";
```

Many IDEs do this also. How is this done?

Edit: Further explaination - I am not asking about the parsing of the text, my question is, once I am past that part.. is there something like a universal XML Scheme, or cross-code format hierarchy that describes which strings are keywords, which characters denote comments, text strings, logic operators, etc. Or must I become a syntax guru for any language I wish to parse accurately?

Comment: The SO highlighter is often wrong (especially in languages which are not called "C#").  Since you don't have the opportunity to tell it what language you're using, it probably just has some heuristics for what's commonly a comment/string/etc. in many common languages.  It's probably a lot less sophisticated than, say, Intellisense (which itself isn't the end-all-be-all of parsers).

Comment: If I had input from a user on what language to parse, how then would I attempt this? Is there an easier method then?

Comment: @stupidkid: See my answer.  What you're asking for is the first step in the compilation process.  It's not trivial to do right.

Comment: Knowing what language is used is important but making a guess on the language is much easier than the parsing. All but the simplest languages will present a challenge to parse. Once you're parsed the code you're over the hump from a highlighting point of view, but it's a steep hurdle. I'm also confused by your comment, on one hand you say you're past the parsing part but later you say you want to parse accurately. Good luck.

Comment: @paulruben - Thanks for your answer. My comment is probably confusing to you because I am using the term 'parsing' as its most generic  meanings - simply absorbing the code into memory, not going as far as to attach meaning to certain words and sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really have your IDE/compiler/interpreter "understand" and colorize code you'll need to parse it and pull out the different syntactical parts. The classic reference for this is the [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29), "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools." You can see some of the difficulty in constructs like this

```
i+++++i;
```

or

```
list<list<hash<list<int>,hash<int,<list>>>>>;
//or just matching parens
```

Properly doing this is a [hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Parsing_and_processing_C.2B.2B_source_code) [problem](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/cc-mode_34.html). Some languages, like java, make this easier than others, such as C and C++ (which both have standards) or ruby (which doesn't even have a spec and relies on the implementation as a spec). However, if you only want to do a few bits of highlighting you can skip large parts of the grammar and get an 80% solution more easily. I suspect that the SO engine knows about strings and a few different types of comments and this does well enough for their purpose.

The difficulty between 80% and 100% is one reason that most IDEs have syntax highlighting for C++ but Visual C++ still doesn't have C++ refactoring support. For highlighting a few mistakes are probably OK. When you're refactoring you need to really understand variable scope in different namespaces and all sorts of pointer stuff too.

Comment: +1 from me, too, for providing a direct link to the Dragon Book.

Answer (score 2):

In order to **correctly** highlight a language, you have to build a *parse tree*.  This requires first tokenizing the string, and then either performing a top-down or a bottom-up parse.  Afterwards, something walks the tree and highlights the portions of the original string corresponding to nodes of a certain sort.

To really understand this, you're going to have to read a book on compiler design/programming language fundamentals.  The relevant topics are *tokenizers*, *parsing*, and *grammars*.

Comment: "Any college course on X" is a good start for a *lot* of questions here, but it's not typically a very helpful answer since the askers aren't often in a position to take such a course.  If they were, they could just go ask the professor instead of hoping us random geeks on the internet will feel like answering them.

Comment: Haha well said Ken. I would love to have the opportunity to take a college course on compilers but that is not possible for my situation.



@Borealid - I am familiar with parse trees, my question is, once I am past that part.. is there something like a universal XML Scheme, or code structuring hierarchy that describes which strings are keywords, which characters denote comments, text strings, logic operators, etc. Or am I to become a syntax master for every language I wish to parse accurately?

Comment: @stupidkid: Tokenization is dealing with a language's *syntax*.  Parsing is dealing with its *semantics*.  XML represents a universal syntax.  There will never be and cannot be universal semantics - they are meaning.  What a "logic operator" is in one language is dependent on the language.  So yes, you have to build a different parser for each language you want to understand.  Take a look, however, at "parser generators" like Bison.  You feed them an abstract description of the language's grammar, and they spit out C source for a parser.